# Correct PHP syntax for relation between models?

Tags: php, relationship

I have 2 Models, Cars & Brands

When I want to create new car and set values everything works like

```
$car->setName('Golf V');
$car->setYear('2015');  // setYear on $car
$car->setNote('This car has electric problems');  // setNote on $car
```

But if I want to set Brand which has relation to other table then I get error: *must be an instance of Salon\Models\Brand* all id's exist, only insert is the problem, what I tried is:

```
$car->setBrand(\Salon\Models\Brand = $_['brand_id']);
$car->setBrand(\Salon\Models\Brand::getId()->$_['brand_id']);
```

It is of course not correct, but can anyone tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: What ORM are we talking about here? Each ORM has its own specific "thingis". However, judging by the error you're not providing the correct instance of a class.

Comment: ORM tag was my error... your message "you're not providing the correct instance of a class." I know, but my problem is how can I do it with correct syntax? I can do $brand = new Brand(); but what to do now with this instance in $car->setBrand();?

Comment: `$car->setBrand($brand->...)` I assume.

Comment: $car->setBrand($brand->getId()), but where can I there give my parameter from post request? i want to store brand id in car table

Comment: Can you provide more code please? Something's funky here. Specifically the whole `$car` class and the `Brand` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should understand the SOLID principles first, to be able to solve these kinds of problems.

You can take a look at [S.O.L.I.D](https://code.tutsplus.com/series/the-solid-principles--cms-634) specially the Interface Segregation Principle